# How to get "short-circuit" behavior for boolean combining operators in RxJava

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

The problem I am trying to solve is like this:

I have a `Flowable<E> items`,
       a `List<Checker<E>> checkers` with size >= 1, where

```
interface Checker<E> {
  Single<Boolean> check(E element)
}
```

and some `doSomethingWith(E element)` method.

What I would like to do is (ignoring async and rxjava for a moment)

```
for(item in items) {
  var allChecksPass = true
  for(checker in checkers) {
    allChecksPass = checker.check(item)
    if (!allChecksPass) break // <--- prevent all further checks!
  }
  if (allChecksPass) doSomethingWith(item)
}
```

Here is my attempt which I do not think is correct or the best way to handle this:

```
items.flatMapMaybe { item: E ->
  Flowable.fromIterable(checkers)
          .flatMapSingle { it.check(item) }
          .any { !it }
          .flatMapMaybe { notAllChecksPassed -> 
             if (notAllChecksPassed) Maybe.empty() else Maybe.just(item)
          }
}
.subscribe { doSomethingWith(it) }
```

The specification of the `Checker<E>` interface is within my control so if needed we could change to a different `check` method signature. However the idea is that the check needs to be async.

Comment: I don't see any problems. `any` stops the upstream when its predicate returns true, which is when one of the checkers succeed with false. You may consider `concatMapSingle` so the checks run one after the other.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make it more readable? Ideally I would have liked to use `all` or similar terminology than double negatives.